# Lambda code getting error while accessing secrets manager

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sftp, aws-secrets-manager

I'm pretty new to lambda and python. i got a readymade code from google for an activity by creating Username and Password based SFTP with Lambda as IdP in AWS Transfer Family.

I have no clue which field i need to add the values of server id, user, password, region, etc... I'm typically cloud admin. This is the cloudwatch error logs getting from this.

ERRORS AUTH_FAILURE Method=password User=new Message="{"errorMessage": "'s-2eccd17fcd5244f68'", "errorType": "KeyError", "requestId": "61a86f3d-7a5b-4763-97e9-f97b74c77d58", "stackTrace": [" File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 22, in lambda_handler\n input_serverId = event[\"s-2eccd17fcd5244f68\"]\n"]}" SourceIP=x.x.x.x

Lambda unable to fetch the password from secrets manager it looks like. i have given sufficient IAM permission for this

Here is the lambda code..

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import os

import json

import boto3

import base64

from ipaddress import ip_network, ip_address

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError





def lambda_handler(event, context):

# Get the required parameters

required_param_list = ["serverId", "username", "protocol", "sourceIp"]

for parameter in required_param_list:

if parameter not in event:

print("Incoming " + parameter + " missing - Unexpected")

return {}



input_serverId = event["serverId"]

input_username = event["username"]

input_protocol = event["protocol"]

input_sourceIp = event["sourceIp"]

input_password = event.get("password", "")

print("ServerId: {}, Username: {}, Protocol: {}, SourceIp: {}"

.format(input_serverId, input_username, input_protocol, input_sourceIp))



# Check for password and set authentication type appropriately. No password means SSH auth

print("Start User Authentication Flow")

if input_password != "":

print("Using PASSWORD authentication")

authentication_type = "PASSWORD"

else:

if input_protocol == 'FTP' or input_protocol == 'FTPS':

print("Empty password not allowed for FTP/S")

return {}

print("Using SSH authentication")

authentication_type = "SSH"



# Retrieve our user details from the secret. For all key-value pairs stored in SecretManager,

# checking the protocol-specified secret first, then use generic ones.

# e.g. If SFTPPassword and Password both exists, will be using SFTPPassword for authentication

secret = get_secret(input_serverId + "/" + input_username)



if secret is not None:

secret_dict = json.loads(secret)

# Run our password checks

user_authenticated = authenticate_user(authentication_type, secret_dict, input_password, input_protocol)

# Run sourceIp checks

ip_match = check_ipaddress(secret_dict, input_sourceIp, input_protocol)



if user_authenticated and ip_match:

print("User authenticated, calling build_response with: " + authentication_type)

return build_response(secret_dict, authentication_type, input_protocol)

else:

print("User failed authentication return empty response")

return {}

else:

# Otherwise something went wrong. Most likely the object name is not there

print("Secrets Manager exception thrown - Returning empty response")

# Return an empty data response meaning the user was not authenticated

return {}





def lookup(secret_dict, key, input_protocol):

if input_protocol + key in secret_dict:

print("Found protocol-specified {}".format(key))

return secret_dict[input_protocol + key]

else:

return secret_dict.get(key, None)





def check_ipaddress(secret_dict, input_sourceIp, input_protocol):

accepted_ip_network = lookup(secret_dict, "AcceptedIpNetwork", input_protocol)

if not accepted_ip_network:

# No IP provided so skip checks

print("No IP range provided - Skip IP check")

return True



net = ip_network(accepted_ip_network)

if ip_address(input_sourceIp) in net:

print("Source IP address match")

return True

else:

print("Source IP address not in range")

return False





def authenticate_user(auth_type, secret_dict, input_password, input_protocol):

# Function returns True if: auth_type is password and passwords match or auth_type is SSH. Otherwise returns False

if auth_type == "SSH":

# Place for additional checks in future

print("Skip password check as SSH login request")

return True

# auth_type could only be SSH or PASSWORD

else:

# Retrieve the password from the secret if exists

password = lookup(secret_dict, "Password", input_protocol)

if not password:

print("Unable to authenticate user - No field match in Secret for password")

return False



if input_password == password:

return True

else:

print("Unable to authenticate user - Incoming password does not match stored")

return False





# Build out our response data for an authenticated response

def build_response(secret_dict, auth_type, input_protocol):

response_data = {}

# Check for each key value pair. These are required so set to empty string if missing

role = lookup(secret_dict, "Role", input_protocol)

if role:

response_data["Role"] = role

else:

print("No field match for role - Set empty string in response")

response_data["Role"] = ""



# These are optional so ignore if not present

policy = lookup(secret_dict, "Policy", input_protocol)

if policy:

response_data["Policy"] = policy



# External Auth providers support chroot and virtual folder assignments so we'll check for that

home_directory_details = lookup(secret_dict, "HomeDirectoryDetails", input_protocol)

if home_directory_details:

print("HomeDirectoryDetails found - Applying setting for virtual folders - "

"Note: Cannot be used in conjunction with key: HomeDirectory")

response_data["HomeDirectoryDetails"] = home_directory_details

# If we have a virtual folder setup then we also need to set HomeDirectoryType to "Logical"

print("Setting HomeDirectoryType to LOGICAL")

response_data["HomeDirectoryType"] = "LOGICAL"



# Note that HomeDirectory and HomeDirectoryDetails / Logical mode

# can't be used together but we're not checking for this

home_directory = lookup(secret_dict, "HomeDirectory", input_protocol)

if home_directory:

print("HomeDirectory found - Note: Cannot be used in conjunction with key: HomeDirectoryDetails")

response_data["HomeDirectory"] = home_directory



if auth_type == "SSH":

public_key = lookup(secret_dict, "PublicKey", input_protocol)

if public_key:

response_data["PublicKeys"] = [public_key]

else:

# SSH Auth Flow - We don't have keys so we can't help

print("Unable to authenticate user - No public keys found")

return {}



return response_data

def get_secret(id):

region = os.environ["SecretsManagerRegion"]

print("Secrets Manager Region: " + region)

print("Secret Name: " + id)



# Create a Secrets Manager client

client = boto3.session.Session().client(service_name="secretsmanager", region_name=region)



try:

resp = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=id)

# Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.

# Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.

if "SecretString" in resp:

print("Found Secret String")

return resp["SecretString"]

else:

print("Found Binary Secret")

return base64.b64decode(resp["SecretBinary"])

except ClientError as err:

print("Error Talking to SecretsManager: " + err.response["Error"]["Code"] + ", Message: " +

err.response["Error"]["Message"])

return None

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: You have included a LOT of code in your question, which nobody is likely to read. Please edit your question to concentrate on the _specific_ issue you are having (eg remove parts related to IPs and just show the parts related to Secrets Manager).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Python code working with Secrets Manager, I recommend getting this Secret Manager Python code working from an IDE. Make sure you can get it working and you understand it.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/secretsmanager/secretsmanager_basics.py

Once you understand that, you can then move to building a Lambda function using this Python code. When you build a Lambda function, you need to make sure that the IAM role you run the Lambda with has permissions to invoke Secret Manager.